# SWT/JFace or Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, jface

Which are the reasons to choose the Eclipse Rich Client Platform as the base of my application, instead of just using SWT/JFace?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Eclipse RCP is not just a GUI (SWT/JFace), but an **[OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434737/whats-new-in-osgi-4-2)**-based platform.

So, you would choose the RCP framework in order to:

- have a better definition of your different modules
- manage their lifecycles, and versions compatibility
- isolate [classloader issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479254/eclipse-rcp-problem-creating-product-which-needs-2-different-versions-of-a-plugi).

If your application is just one monolithic GUI font-end, RCP might be a bit overkill.

Comment: I'd like to amend that RCP adds more than just OSGi (see [Roland Tepp's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2055496/2986905)) which is a burden or not, depedning on the use case at hand. And SWT/JFace can also run on OSGi without RCP.

Answer (score 17):

In additions to points that [VonC has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505292/swt-jface-or-eclipse-rcp/1505508#1505508) (OSGi platform goodies: modularity, classloader isolation, extensible architecture), the Eclipse RCP provides many application level services that might ease the overall development of your final product:

With Eclipse RCP you'll get:

- Ready and extensible UI application framework

  - *perspectives* for separating discrete application areas
  - *views* and *editors* for providing reusable blocks of UI with lifecycle of their own
  - *Commands* abstraction with key bindings, contextual handlers and bindings to toolbars and menus
- All the goodies of the whole eclipse ecosystem

  - [p2 provisioning](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started) for managing installation and automatic updates of your application
  - [ECF communication framework](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/)
  - [BIRT reporting tools](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/)
  - [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/) and [modeling tools](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/)
  - lots more...

Of course - the latter part does not necessarily mean you have to use the behemoth that is Eclipse RCP platform to gain the advantages those offer.

Depending on the scope of your application, you might do well to just use Equinox as an underlying OSGi container and build your own GUI client on top of that.

Also keep in mind that Eclipse RCP is no more the only game in town when making a decision of GUI frameworks in SWT/JFace land. There are serious contenders that might suite your needs better:

- [Riena Platform Project](http://www.eclipse.org/riena/) is quoting their own words *"the foundation for building multi-tier enterprise client/server applications"*
- [E4 Project](http://www.eclipse.org/e4/) project is a work in progress to build the next generation of the eclipse RCP platform with much more modular design in mind.

**Edit:**
Eclipse e4 project has graduated from being just a work in progress since my original answer was posted and now has become a fully usable rich client application framework/platform of its own. It has matured to the point where it is now being used as an underlying platform for the latest Eclipse 4.2 (Indigo) IDE.

Answer (score 5):

Just my 2 pennies worth, but vanilla SWT/JFace can be less of a learning curve. I like the fact they're just simple GUIs, you don't need to learn the "platform" (as in the RCP way), just get to grips with the SWT components and build you're GUI! Overall, I see it as simpler (but then I don't really know much about RCP!).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 4 dependency injection mechanism is a great asset, to choose Eclipse RCP,
and Now with E4, the platform can be very lightweight,

Add to this e4 tools with it model editor, let you save a lot of time